# Is there a way to set CRS in st_sfc

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Did something recently change with the sf library?  My code, which has been working for a long time, no longer works.  Here is what I am doing...

```
pt1 = st_point(c(lowerLeftLong, lowerLeftLat))
pt2 = st_point(c(upperRightLong, upperRightLat))
sfcAoi = st_sfc(pt1, pt2, crs = 4326)
st_set_precision(sfcAoi, 0.000001)
print("**********")
print(st_geometry(sfcAoi))
print("----------")
```

When I print it, I get the following:

```
Geometry set for 2 features
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -81.45641 ymin: 27.78719 xmax: -81.37779 ymax: 27.85796
CRS:           NA
POINT (-81.45641 27.78719)
POINT (-81.37779 27.85796)
```

Notice, CRS is set to NA.
I have tried several ways to do this, but I cannot get CRS to be anything other than NA.

```
st_crs(sfc) = "EPSG:4326" #does not work
st_set_crs(sfcAoi, 4326) #does not work
```

On top of this, I have looked at the official documentation and copied one of their examples.  This is what happens...

```
p1 = st_point(c(7,52))
p2 = st_point(c(-30,20))
sfc = st_sfc(p1, p2, crs = 4326)
sfc
st_transform(sfc, 3857)
```

Output below

```
Error in st_transform.sfc(sfc, 3857) :
  cannot transform sfc object with missing crs
Calls: st_transform -> st_transform.sfc
```

Comment: Does the accepted answer here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692695/coordinate-transformation-of-sf-sfc-object-does-not-seem-to-be-working

Comment: Sadly no.  In fact, the code above works in my Rstudio, but does not work on ubuntu.

Perhaps there is a difference where sf 0.9,8 works, but sf 1.0.5 does not?

Comment: What does `library(sf)` say about the libraries its linking to? Specifically, PROJ and GDAL? Does that `st_set_precision` do anything here? (If not, take it out of the question). All your examples work for me with sf 1.0.5 "Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1;" on Ubuntu. Do you have any other packages loaded? Has everything come from CRAN?

Comment: I think you were onto something Spacedman.  I ended up uninstalling all of the packages and reinstalling them. (GDAL, SF) and it worked again.  I am not sure what happened, but it's working now.  Thanks for the help.